# Incorrect output when filtering based on product

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Cart (
    Id_cart INT NOT NULL,
    Id_product VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE product (
    id_product VARCHAR(25),
    id_vendor INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Id INT,
    Id_cart INT NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(25),
  order_no VARCHAR(25),
  id_vendor INT NOT NULL

);

-- data
INSERT INTO Cart
    (Id_cart, id_product)
VALUES

    (1, 'abc002'),
    (1, 'abc003')
;
INSERT INTO product
    (id_product, id_vendor)
VALUES

    ('abc002',2),
    ('abc003',3)
;
INSERT INTO Orders
    (Id, Id_cart,status,order_no,id_vendor)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'pending','aaa001',2),
    (2, 1, 'pending','aaa002',3)
```

This is my sql query used to display output

```
Select c.id_cart,order_no,id_product from orders as o
left join  (SELECT * FROM cart) c using(id_cart) where id_product = 'abc002'
//
//output
id_cart     order_no    id_product
1            aaa001     abc002
1            aaa002     abc002
//
//expected output
id_cart     order_no    id_product
1            aaa001     abc002
```

I want it to show only the order_no which belong id_product (abc0002) instead of showing all the order_no with the same id_cart of id_product(abc0002).

How can i do this? Anything wrong with my query? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oof. Owie. My bones.

First things first, for the love of things please keep it somewhat clean, there's so much wrong with query it hurts my eyes. I'm not even certain what it is you're trying to achieve truth be told. From what I can see you're not using left join properly. You also have no PKs, which could've made things easier. I'm also not sure what purpose cart is serving in this statement.

Try the below and please review how and why it works if that's what you're looking for:

```
SELECT o.id_cart, o.order_no, p.id_product FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN product p ON o.id_vendor =  p.id_vendor
LEFT JOIN cart c ON p.id_product = c.id_product
WHERE p.id_product = 'abc002'
```